# MVC4: How to sort this selectlist/dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select, selectlist

I'm working with MVC4.

I have this following dropdownlist/selectlist:

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmployerID", String.Empty)

ViewBag.EmployerID = new SelectList(db.Employers, "EmployerID", "Name", contact.EmployerID);
```

and I want this dropdownlist/selectlist to be sorted by the "Name". What should I do?

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 7):

Add [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) to your `db.Employers`

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmployerID", String.Empty)

ViewBag.EmployerID = new SelectList(db.Employers.OrderBy(x => x.Name), 
    "EmployerID", "Name", contact.EmployerID);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.However that does not work.The selectlist is still sorted by the EmployerID.

Comment: Old thread, but if this wasn't working for you, maybe you updated your Controller's POST method and not the GET method?

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would share this solution that I came up with, in case others have the same issue I had.
I’m working with a generics and thus I cannot order my source before creating the SelectList.
However, you can order a generated SelectList.  I still wanted my method to return a SelectList, so I call the SelectList()
a second time using the ordered SelectList as the source.   :)

```
var orderedSelectList = new SelectList(source, "YourValueFieldName", "YourTextFieldName", selectedCode).OrderBy(i => i.Text);
return new SelectList(orderedSelectList, "Value", "Text", selectedCode);
```